# Javascript time taken to check null condition in an if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, linked-list

I was just practicing a Javascript solution to a linked list problem (reverse a linked list) when I observed the following. When my code contained this snippet:

```js
while(head!=null) {
   temp = head.next
   head.next = prev
   prev = head
   head = temp
 }
```

This took 96ms and some 43.6MB.

It was correct but not in even in the top 50% with respect to speed, so I randomly decided to omit the `!=null` part of the `if` statement to see what happens.

```js
 while(head) {
   temp = head.next
   head.next = prev
   prev = head
   head = temp 
 }
```

To my surprise, this reduced time to 63ms and placed it faster than 96% of the solutions! Memory taken increased slightly to 44.2MB as well. But I am confused as to why this simple change caused such a drastic speed up?

If I had to guess, I would say that the second scenario merely checks if `head` *exists*, while the first scenario actually evaluates `head` first and then explicitly compares it to `null`, or something like this. Even if this is correct, I am surprised by the speed improvement. Any insight on this?

Edit: At a suggestion in the comments I also tried `(head !== null)`, which at 64ms was definitely faster than the first scenario but same as the second!

Comment: `!=`  have you tried `!==`,  The reason is that none strict compares have a much larger overhead, due to type coercion.   Generally speaking try and avoid none strict compare's anyway.  You might even find `!==` is even faster, as `while(head)` will also be doing more.

Comment: Comparisons have more overhead than type conversions. (Though I wouldn't've thought it would be that much.) See [JavaScript type coercion explained](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839/). Your first example checks if `head` isn't `null` or `undefined` (a special case with comparisons). Your second example is doing a type conversion to boolean (objects are always true, `null` is always false).

Comment: @Keith good suggestion! I tried that, and it is 64ms - so essentially the same as my second scenario.